# How to integrate Azure Service Bus with Windows Store apps

Tags: c#, azure, windows-store-apps, azureservicebus, azure-servicebusrelay

I am working on a Windows Store app which is connected to Azure Service Bus Topic. I want to use the service bus topics in my application. Is this possible? I can't use NamespaceManager which is discussed here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-topics/ , because it's not supported by Windows Store. The idea is to make subscriptions.

My question is simply, is this possible to do? And what approach should I choose?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at using the [Service Bus REST APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh780752.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are libs/NuGet packages for using Service Bus Queues / Topics from Windows Store apps:
http://www.nuget.org/packages/windowsazure.messaging.managed
http://www.nuget.org/packages/windowsazure.messaging

Also a sample is available here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Service-Bus-WinRT-and-b31312a2